# ESRI ArcGIS: Map.ZoomOut()

Tags: wpf, arcgis, esri

Is there a method to zoom out of a map? Like the oposite of:

```
    Map.Zoom(3);
```

Changing 3 to -3 does not work:

```
    Map.Zoom(-3); //No exception, it wont work like this
```

I'm developing in visual studio with C# (WPF)

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like [the documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-wpf/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Map~Zoom.html) says:

> Factor=0.5 zooms out to half the scale. Factor=2 zooms in to twice the scale.

Therefore, you probably want to do this:

```
Map.Zoom(1.0 / 3.0);
```